# If binomial expansion holds for $(A+B)^n$, does it follow that $A$ ad $B$ commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A, B$ be $2 \times 2$ real matrices. Is $AB=BA$ if $(A+B)^3=A^3+3A^2B+3AB^2+B^3$?
>
> Also, generalization for arbitrary positive integer $n$ is appreciated.

This is not a homework problem, but something that interests me.

Comment: Matrices are singular or not?

Comment: You don't know, that is part of the problem

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea for the general case, but for cubic power, the answer is no. Here is a counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&1},\ B=\pmatrix{1&-1\\ 2&-2},\ AB-BA=\pmatrix{2&-2\\ 2&-2}\ne0.
$$
Both $(A+B)^3$ and $A^3+3A^2B+3AB^2+B^3$ are equal to $\pmatrix{1&0\\ 2&-1}$.

Comment: in the case of $n=2$ it works...

Comment: Wow, I wonder what is the intuition behind these matrices, are they from luck, or is there any hidden principles?

Comment: @user1551 yes, it does I guess, I just wanted to add that it works for $(A+B)^2$ to make your answer a bit more general

Comment: @Algebra1128 I just put some constraints on $A$ and $B$ and solve the equation. More specifically, I assume that both $A$ and $B$ are singular and the trace of $A+B$ is zero. This simplifies the boxed equality in question to $ABA+BAB=0$. I tried to solve this by using a nilpotent $A$ at first, but it didn't work. So, on the second trial, I tried the current $A$ and it worked.

Comment: but it has to be so, doesn't it: $(A+B)^2=A^2+AB+BA+B^2=A^2+2AB+B^2$ and therefore $AB+BA=2AB \Leftrightarrow BA=AB$ or am I on the completely wrong track? I haven't checked your calculations though...

Comment: @user190080 Oh, I see what you mean now. Yes, of course, when $n=2$, $A$ and $B$ must commute.

Comment: yeah...ok, I was already a bit concerned by myself :) So the answer in case of $n=2$ is yes, $n=3$ no and well...,my guess is that it won't hold for any other $n_0>2$

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.  :)